# more realistic Pressure simulation in Blender

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am currently working on the simulation of **pneumatic objects an structures** and have a few questions for you.
If you assign a vertex group to the object (Cloth -> pressure -> shape), the assigned vertex group will stiffen.
Up to this point everything works fine.
My problem is that the simulation is not realistic, because the marked vertex does not approach as it is usually the case with inflatable bodies. You can see this Problem in the pictures. In best case **X** is getting smaller when the object i blown up.

Do you have an idea what i can do to have a more realistic simulation?
Thank you!
[image: X has the same length]

[image]

Comment: You could move the 2 parts towards each other with 2 Hook modifiers for example

Comment: @TOLLMUTH: keep in mind that it is a graphic software - not a simulation software....